# Function in an app that gives alert message when somenone updates list?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I have build an app to get list items etc. Now I want to put a function in it that gives alert message when someone adds,removes or changes something in list. 
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a remote event receiver for this. see [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220043.aspx)

Check also [github](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP/tree/master/Samples/Core.EventReceivers)

Comment: Ok I'll try. thx.

Comment: Yes it helped. thx!